# How can I open the binary file which is created using a C program?

Tags: c, sockets, binary

I have implemented a C program where raw packets are received from the network and saved in a binary file,but C can't open the binary file. I tried opening it using terminal, but I was getting permission denied. What am I supposed to do in order to open the binary file?

```
 int main()
  {
     int saddr_size , data_size;
     struct sockaddr saddr;
     gopromiscous();
     unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(1024);  

     logfile=fopen("sniff_data.bin","wb");

     if(logfile==NULL)
      {
       printf("Unable to create sniff_data file.");
      }
     printf("\n Starting..\n");

     int sock_raw = socket( AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_ALL)) ;
     setsockopt(sock_raw , SOL_SOCKET , SO_BINDTODEVICE , "eth0" , strlen("eth0")+ 1 );

     if(sock_raw < 0)
      {
    //Print the error with proper message
        perror("Socket Error");
        return 1;
      }
      int count=30; 
      while(count>=0)
        { 
           count--;
           saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
           //Receive a packet
           data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 1024, 0 , &saddr ,                   (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
           if(data_size <0 )
            {
              printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
              return 1;
            }


      fwrite(buffer, data_size, 1, logfile);

        //Now process the packet
      ProcessPacket(buffer , data_size);
         }
       fclose(logfile);
       close(sock_raw);
       printf("\n");
       printf(" Finished\n\n");
       return 0;
  }
```

Comment: maybe add more access permissions? Also make sure that the file is closed after you finished writing it

Comment: @shisira: I think raw packets need `sudo` permissions. Try executing your program with sudo permissions.

Comment: what if recieve error|socket error happens? Your file is never `fclose()`ed.

Comment: @Raju , i used sudo ./sniff_data.bin in the terminal. still cannot open it.

Comment: i have closed the file.

Comment: @shishira you want to EXECUTE the file?

Comment: `sudo ./sniff_data.bin` will try to execute the file. And since the file(I am very sure) will not have executable permissions, you get 'permission denied'

Comment: try reading the file with `cat ./sniff_data.bin`...

Comment: @shishira Add output of "ls -l" for you file.

Comment: ya i dont have to execute that binary file. but how will i check if it has written into the bianry file. i mean to say cant i view the binary file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on Linux and that the binary file is named "file".

First, check the permissions of the file:

```
ls -l file
```

If you can read it, the permissions should look a bit like this:

```
-rw-r--r--
```

The first three letters are the permissions of the user, the next three of the group and the last three of other. If there are all "r"'s (or just the ones you need), you are good to go.

If not, you can give yourself permissions to read the file in question:

```
chmod +r file
```

To actually read the file, you can try an editor like vim or a command like cat:

```
cat -v file
```

(Add `-v` to `cat` to avoid messing up the terminal, in which case you can type `reset`).

Here's one way of reading (and outputting) the file in C:

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main ()
{
  char *buffer;
  struct stat s;

  int fd = open ("file", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  fstat (fd, &s);

  buffer = mmap (0, s.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
  if (buffer != (void *) -1) {
    fwrite (buffer, s.st_size, 1, stdout);
    munmap (buffer, s.st_size);
  }

  close (fd);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(example from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_entire_file#C)

Compile with:

```
gcc -O2 main.c -o main
```

Then read the file by executing the program:

```
./main
```

To view the file in binary format (as ones and zeros) you can use this command:

```
xxd -b file
```

Comment: the size of the file isnt zero and it has -rw-rw-r-- permission.  if i use cat command i will get the text i mean to say i want to view the file in binary format.

Comment: What do you mean "in binary format?" Do you want to view the file as ones and zeros instead of as characters?

Comment: i had implemented this program to store it in a text file. but now i am suppose to save it in a binary file. so i am struggling here :(

Answer (score 1):

There could be some reasons here:

1. The file is in use - see in your code, where you are dumping the binary into the file, that you actually `fclose()` the file pointer.
2. See if you have read permissions on the file, if not, use `chmod` to add permissions.
3. See if you have ownership permissions, and that YOU are the owner of the file. If not, use `chown` to change the ownership to your username.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "open the file"?
Do you see the file that was created?
In general, run "`ls -l <filename>`" on your file and see that its size is not 0.
Then also check the permissions.
Perhaps you have run the C program as root/sudo and now trying to open the file as a regular user?

Edit: I see in your comment that you ran the command with "sudo" - this is the reason why you can't open the file as your own user.
Run "`sudo chown <username> <filename>`" to gain ownership of the file.

Comment: changing file permissions to execute a text file, is a very bad thing to do. :-)

Comment: @Aniket Indeed, but I wrote this because I didn't know what does the OP mean by "open the file". I edited the answer - the original question now contains comment that says that the program was ran with "sudo".

Comment: size of the file isnt 0. and it has -rw-rw-r-- permission.